# What do you call non-standard spellings used by companies that are similar to real English words?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are many brand names that are misspellings of real English words. Instead of calling them misspellings I would like a more positive term for this type of name.

Comment: Creative spellings?

Comment: Homophonic spellings

Comment: Already answered at [Is there a word for people who deliberately disregard standard spelling?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379106/is-there-a-word-for-people-who-deliberately-disregard-standard-spelling/403627#403627). Max Williams gives 'sensational spelling' there.

Comment: Maybe you could add some examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia calls it [sensational spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling):

> Sensational spelling is the deliberate spelling of a word in an incorrect or non-standard way for special effect.
>
> Sensational spellings are common in advertising and product placement. In particular, brand names such as Cadbury's "Creme Egg" (standard English spelling: cream), Weetabix (wheat), Blu-ray (blue), Kellogg's "Froot Loops" (fruit) or Hasbro's Playskool (school) may use unexpected spellings to draw attention to or trademark an otherwise common word.

Comment: Yeah, but some of these are because you cannot legally describe something as "cream" when it has none, or "fruit" when it only tastes of it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think it's still a good answer, though.